# WebStorm Breaking Line with no indentation

Tags: eslint, webstorm

Ok, so here's the deal: I'm coding with WebStorm, and using ESLint rules to write my code. One of these rules is that there should be no trailing spaces. Which means that if I break a line so two blocks of code are separated visually, that separating line should have no whitespaces at all.

However, when I break a line, the blank separating line receives the same indentation as the line that I broke from. So if it is inside a function, it receives the function indentation, say, for instance, four spaces. That triggers a ESLint warning about having no trailing spaces. What I usually have to do is manually delete those four spaces so the ESLint warning goes away, which is really annoying.

I thought a good solution to this issue would be the following behavior: if I press enter to break a line, the line initially have no spaces at all (which means ESLint will not trigger a warning). However, as soon as I type any character that isn't a newline break (as in, I press any key besides enter), it automatically creates the indentation from the previous line.

Is there any way to achieve this? If not, is there any way I can work smoothly without having to manually delete the indentation every single time?

Answer (score 0):

On hitting `Enter`, new line is indented according to code style preferences, so the corresponding number of white spaces/tabs is added.

You don't necessary need deleting the white spaces manually - with **Strip trailing spaces on Save** option enabled, they are auto-removed on **Save All** (Ctrl+S); you can also disable **Keep indents on empty lines** in formatter preferences (**Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Tabs and Indents**) to make sure that they are deleted on code reformatting, but you can't avoid them being added on `Enter`

We have a feature request to optionally trim the trailing white spaces on moving a caret to next line, [IDEA-119109](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119109/Trim-white-space-added-by-auto-indent-when-moving-caret-off-the-line),please feel free to vote for it